# how to Bypass cross origin call editor.swagger.io in documentation of API

Tags: api, swagger

While running the yaml file in editor i am getting this message:

```
"This is a cross-origin call. Make sure the server at sitedomain.com accepts GET requests from editor.swagger.io."
```

Is there any alternate way to get response directly not through **editor,swagger.io**.
 thanks in advance.